# Delete node with all incoming and outgoing relationships

Tags: neo4j, relationship, cypher, neo4jphp

I want to delete node with all incoming and outgoing relationships.

This incoming and outgoing relationships are optional.

```
(t:Teacher)-[:TEACHES]->(s:Student)
(s:Student)-[:ATTENDS]->(c:Class)
```

Student node have optional relationship with Teacher and optional relationship with Class.

I want to delete Student node with {id:1}.

I know how to delete all nodes and relationships with:

```
MATCH (n)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
DELETE n,r
```

But not able to convert it for specific node. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the discriminating property to the first match clause

```
MATCH (s:Student {id:1})
OPTIONAL MATCH s-[r]-()
DELETE r, s
```

If instead by `id` you mean the internal node id and not a property that you have set, then

```
MATCH (s)
WHERE ID (s) = 1
OPTIONAL MATCH s-[r]-()
DELETE r, s
```

should work. It is irregular and usually bad to lay hold of nodes by their internal id.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close:

```
match (n:Student) 
where n.studentid = 2224
optional match (n)-[r]-()
delete n,r
```

(updated based on jjaderberg's comment)

Comment: I tried this but it failed. Getting error : `javax.transaction.HeuristicRollbackException: Failed to commit transaction Transaction(866, owner:"qtp1165358333-120")[STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION,Resources=1], transaction rolled back ---> javax.transaction.xa.XAException`

Comment: I think your original query was good but you have to put the `WHERE` clause with the first `MATCH` clause. `n.id` is a property called `id`. `ID(n)` refers to the internal node id, which is not a property. The optional match is necessary for deleting the node also when it doesn't have any relationships.

Comment: good catch - knew I put it in there originally for a reason.. :)